# Angular Material datepicker have blank pop up

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-material

I use angular material and I would like to implement md-datepicker. I do something like here :

```
<md-input-container flex="100" layout="row">
    <div flex="45">
        <md-datepicker ng-model="$ctrl.myDate" placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Js looks like here:

```
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.myDate = new Date();
```

I have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtmKY.png)
Where I do mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have loaded the correct libraries, and the version.

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
  
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.css">    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
   <md-content>
      <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find problem, but don't know why it happens. When I replace

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

to :

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.js"></script>
```

Problem was gone, but I want local src so tried npm install, after remove folder with angular material, but it's not help